# Calling stored procedure in EF asynchronously using c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, async-await

My C# MVC application is using EF to call a stored procedure in db.  in Context.cs(which is auto generated) file, code looks like below

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> Proc_sp(Nullable<int> x, Nullable<int> y)
    {
        var xParameter = x.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("x", x) :
            new ObjectParameter("x", typeof(int));

        var yParameter = y.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("y", y) :
            new ObjectParameter("y", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("Proc_sp", x, y);
    }
```

and i call this using below code

```
var check = ctx.Proc_sp(x, y).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

My question is, how do i make this code async.  I tried changing the context.cs to as below

```
public virtual async Task<ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>> Proc_sp(Nullable<int> x, Nullable<int> y)
        {
 var query =  base.Database.SqlQuery<ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>>("exec Proc_SP @x @y",
           new SqlParameter("@x", x),
           new SqlParameter("@y", y)
            );

            return  await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

when i do this, am getting below error in the calling part

Error   CS1061  'Task<ObjectResult<int?>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ObjectResult<int?>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the correct way to change Context.cs file so that i dont have to change below line

```
var check = ctx.Proc_sp(x, y).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

My object is to make the sp call async without making change to the caller or with minimal change(I underestand caller has to make some minimal changes like FirstOrDefault to FirstOrDefaultAsync).  Is there any other best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m not sure without writing some code together but why are you calling .ToList ? Could you just call FirstOrDefault without ToList or is that invalid code?

Comment: Firstly you should suffix `Proc_spAsync` secondly if you have an async method, you will need to await it `await  Proc_spAsync(x, y)` obviously you cant `ToList` it, you have already called FirstOrDefault in the actual method

Comment: @S.Walker That is an existing code. is removing ToList is only option?  After removing ToList in client code i get below error
Error CS1061 'Task<ObjectResult<int?>>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ObjectResult<int?>>' could be found

Comment: @TheGeneral changing name of sp is not a issue.  but is the code correct way to handle ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> to make it async?

Answer (score -1):

You have to `await` the task returned by `Proc_sp` to get the result of the task:

```
var check = await ctx.Proc_sp(x, y);
```

Comment: when i do that, i get below error 'int?' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'int?' could be found (are you missing a u

Comment: If `Proc_sp` returns `Task<ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>>`, that's impossible.